# What is the correct translation of rig veda 8:1:1?

Tags: rig-veda, translation-request

Rig veda 8:1:1

> मा चि॑द॒न्यद्वि शं॑सत॒ सखा॑यो॒ मा रि॑षण्यत । इन्द्र॒मित्स्तो॑ता॒ वृष॑णं॒ सचा॑ सु॒ते मुहु॑रु॒क्था च॑ शंसत ॥
>
> महान् आत्मा ईश्वर को छोड़ के जो मूढ़ जड़ सूर्य्यादिकों की, मानवकल्पित विष्णुप्रभृतियों की और अवस्तु=प्रेत मृत पितृगण यक्ष गन्धर्व आदिकों की उपासना करते हैं, वे आत्महन् हो महान् अन्धकार में गिरते हैं, अतः सब छोड़ केवल ब्रह्म उपासनीय है, यह शिक्षा इससे देते हैं।<sup>[Source](http://xn--j2b3a4c.com/rigveda/8/1/1)</sup>
>
> Great souls except God who are foolish roots worshiping Suryadikas, human imagined Vishnuprabhritis and Avastu = phantom dead ancestors, Yaksha Gandharva worshipers, they fall into great darkness, so all are left only Brahm is worshiped, this education is given by this Huh.

What is the correct translation of this verse, because this verse is showing some kind of monotheism of Abrahamic religion.

---

<sup>I used Google translater to translate it in English from hindi</sup>

Comment: FYI, Sanatan Dharma is monoTHEistic but polytheistic i.e. there is literally only one supreme Bhagavan (it's the same as God or Allah). In fact, all religions accept that there can only be 1 Supreme. He is like the CEO. All the Devas who report to like like Brahma, Indra, Shiva are like CTO, CIO etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is how Prof Wilson translates the verse

> Repeat, friends, no other praise, be not hurtful (to yourselves);
> praise together Indra, the showerer (of benefits) when the Soma is
> effused; repeatedly utter praise (to him). -RV 8.1.1

It has nothing to do with "foolish roots worshipers" and so on. The verse is just praising Indra.

Answer (score 0):

griffith 's translation -

> GLORIFY naught besides, O friends; so shall no sorrow trouble you.
> Praise only mighty Indra when the juice is shed, and say your lauds repeatedly

Dr tulsi ram's translation -
https://archive.org/details/wg868/page/n2637/mode/2up?view=theater